# Add value to specific Class property from List

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

This solution seems to me as a very lazy and cheap way to do this and I was wondering if there was any better or more future proof way to do this with as minimal change needed if I wish to add new 'Skills' in the future so to speak.

All I have to do here is specific add levels to the properties in the list, I know what list index belongs to which level. Example: Index 0 contains strength, and defense is index 2. But this might change in the future.

```
public class SkillLogic
{
    RpgRepository _skillRpgRepository = new RpgRepository(new DatabaseSkillContext());

    public List<Skill> ProcessSkills(int strength, int constitution, int defense, int dexterity, int intelligence, int charisma, int willpower, int perception, int luck)
    {
        List<Skill> skills = _skillPotionSmashersRepository.GetSkills();

        skills[0].Level = strength;
        skills[1].Level = constitution;
        skills[2].Level = defense;
        skills[3].Level = dexterity;
        skills[4].Level = intelligence;
        skills[5].Level = charisma;
        skills[6].Level = willpower;
        skills[7].Level = perception;
        skills[8].Level = luck;

        return skills;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating an Enum (StatsType perhaps?) with entries for strength, constitution etc. Then your code could be more self documenting.

Even better, change GetSkills to return a Dictionary rather than a List - with the dictionary Key being of type StatsType.